# Why do I get a StackOverflowException when using Html.RenderAction in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, stack-overflow

I am converting a WebForms application to Razor and everything works fine except when I try to use `Html.RenderAction`. Whenever I call this, I get a `StackOverflowException`. Does anyone have an idea on what might be causing this?

The template for my action looks like this:

```
@model dynamic   

should be rendering this
```

In my _Layout.cshtml file I render the action like this:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("MyPartialAction");}
```

My `_ViewStart.cshtml` file looks as follows:

```
@{
    this.Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that your template for your action does not define a Layout to be used. Therefore, it automatically gets the one specified in the _ViewStart.cshtml file. This will in effect cause the _Layout.cshtml file to be nested within itself *ad infinitum*. Hence the `StackOverflowException`. The solution is simple. Set the Layout within your action template to `null`:

```
@model dynamic
@{
   Layout = null;
}
should be rendering this
```

Now the template won't request to be embedded in a layout file and everything works fine.

Comment: Or use the correct method and call [`Html.RenderPartial()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492503(v=vs.118).aspx).